# Size of \baselineskip for \\ if font size is \footnotesize?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\footnotesize]

\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0, rectangle, red, draw, minimum width=0.5cm](A) {%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5cm}%
x\\
x
\end{minipage}};

\node[inner sep=0, rectangle, blue, draw, minimum width=0.5cm, anchor=north west](B) at (0.5cm, -\baselineskip) {%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5cm}%
x\\
x
\end{minipage}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I align the two rectangles that it looks like...

[image]

You get this result if \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\footnotesize] is commented out. The problem is that I need a smaller font size. I have tried to set the shift to -\footnotesep but no success.

Comment: `\baselineskip` under `\footnotesize` is 9.5pt; see `{\footnotesize\the\baselineskip}`.

Comment: As in the previous question, the title is misleading, the issue is not with `\\ ` but rather a tikz question of how to propagate alignment from inner boxes to the outer node. The alignment you want is automatic with `\begin{minipage}[b]{5mm}...\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{5mm}...\end{minipage}` so your question is not about `\\ ` and `\baselineskip` but about how to add the tikz boxes without breaking alignment. (Also it should not be tagged pdftex as you see same with classic tex or xetex or luatex)

Comment: @Werner: Is it possible to set a new length to '\footnotesize\the\baselineskip' so that I can use it in Tikz? I have tried '\newlength{\mylength}\setlength{\mylength}{\footnotesize\the\baselineskip}' but no success.

Comment: @user4811: Of course, just `\setlength{\mylength}{9.5pt}` would work. :) But you can also try `{\footnotesize\global\setlength{\mylength}{\baselineskip}}`.

Comment: @Werner: Woohoo, this works! Thx!

Answer (score 3):

If you can use [`TiKZ v 3.0.0`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/), it introduces a new `node` option called `node font` which is used to compute all dimensions of node, while `font` option only affects text inside the node and not to its dimensions.

With this version is easy to get what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\verb+node font=\footnotesize+

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={node font=\footnotesize}]
    \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0, rectangle, red, draw, 
          text width=0.5cm, align=left](A) {%
          x\\
          x
    };
    \node[inner sep=0, rectangle, blue, draw, 
          text width=0.5cm, align=left, anchor=north west](B) 
          at (0.5cm, -\baselineskip) {%
          x\\
          x
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\verb+font=\footnotesize+

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}]
    \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0, rectangle, red, draw, 
          text width=0.5cm, align=left](A) {%
          x\\
          x
    };
    \node[inner sep=0, rectangle, blue, draw, 
          text width=0.5cm, align=left, anchor=north west](B) 
          at (0.5cm, -\baselineskip) {%
          x\\
          x
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've also made some changes to your code:

1. used `/.style` instead of `tikzstyle`. Please look at [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)
2. deleted `minipages` inside nodes. Text node is similar to a `minipage`, you need to fix a `text width` and some `align` option to use `\\` inside nodes to break lines.

Comment: Thx! This solved at least the alignment problem of a node shifted by \baselineskip. Do you know how I can shift an arrow by \baselineskip? Adding "\draw[->] (0.6cm, 0) -- (2cm, 0); \draw[->] (1.1cm, -\baselineskip) -- (2cm, -\baselineskip);" to your example illustrate the problem. The \baselineskip is different for the "arrow shift" and I don't know why.